# Find "mystring" in files and return only certain portion of matching lines on linux

Tags: linux

There's another (unanswered) question with this same title but aimed at windows. I want to know how to do this in linux.

I have this: `find ./ -type f -exec grep -H 'mystring' {} \;`, which will find the string and return the whole line... but I want to use this on a file which only contains one long line, so I'd like to be able to receive just the context before and after the found string.

Comment: "on a file which only contains one long line" – Investigating the reason may lead to better solutions. E.g. maybe the file is in fact a sequence of lines, but with null character (not newline character) being the terminator; in such case GNU `grep -z` would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep -o` that will show you matching parts instead of whole lines. If there are two or more matches in a line then they will be printed on separate output lines.

To see `mystring` with neighboring characters, you need to expand the pattern so it matches the neighboring characters as well. The following command will search for (and print) `mystring` with up to 10 characters to the left and up to 10 characters to the right:

```
grep -oE '.{0,10}mystring.{0,10}'
```

(without `-E` you would need `.\{0,10\}mystring.\{0,10\}` which does not look that nice).

Notes and quirks:

- `-o` is not portable, your `grep` may or may not support it. GNU `grep` does support `-o`.
- Do not try to match exactly 10 characters. Allowing less is crucial when `mystring` occurs near the beginning or near the end of a line. Note `.{0,10}` is greedy, so you will get as close to 10 as possible.
- Inside `mystring 2345 mystring …` the command will find one occurrence of the pattern, not two. You will see `mystring 2345 myst` and then the search for the next occurrence will start at `ring`, missing one match.
- Similarly `mystring 234567890foo mystring …` will print `mystring 234567890` and the search for the next occurrence will start at `foo`. It will find the second `mystring`, but it will print `foo mystring …`, not `567890foo mystring …`.
- If your `grep` supports `-r` (meaning "read all files under each directory, recursively") then maybe you don't need `find`. Example:

  ```
  grep -rHoE '.{0,10}mystring.{0,10}' ./
  ```

  `find` will be useful if you want to perform additional tests though.